# leaflet map grey screen for geoJSON Layer

Tags: leaflet

Wondering if anyone can help, it's a bit of a strange one. My leaflet map works in isolation, but when added to some existing code the geoJSON (world-map.geojson) appears not to be added to a layer, I just get a grey screen with the leaflet map controls. However, when the leaflet.css is commented out you can see the geoJSON layer has been added... I get no errors and If I comment out references to other JS files it makes no difference.

As this appears to be conflict of sorts i'm not expected a hard and fast answer, but if anyone has come across this before or could suggest any pointers it would be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="world-map.geojson"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>
<script src="map.js"></script>
```

JS - stripped right back

```
var geojson,
    layer,
    map = L.map('map').setView([43.8476, 18.3564],3);

// style each continent
function countriesStyle(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: "#FED976",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: "white",
        dashArray: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

// add layer
geojson = L.geoJson(countries, {
    style: countriesStyle,
    maxZoom: 2,
    minZoom: 2
}).addTo(map);

// works. countries var is in the DOM
for(var i = 0; i < countries.features.length; i++) {
    console.log(countries.features[i].properties.name)
}
```

Comment: I see your Leaflet CSS version is 1.0.3, what about the Leaflet JS version?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The JS version is the same, 1.0.3. I have tried using the latest version of both the CSS and JS, 1.2.0, but it made no difference. I think I'm going to have to dissect my code and add it back bit by bit until I find the issue.

Comment: I've got it! Found the issue. My piece has an svg and when I first added it I was lazy and just used this svg {width: 100%; } - obviously caused issues and targeted the map as well.